# Can't add Azure App Service certificate to UK West App Service

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service

I purchased a App Service Certificate via the Azure portal and successfully added it to my North Europe App Service.  I have also created a UK West App Service with the same domains validated but I get an error when trying to import it.

The only Error information I can find tells me to look at the error:

> TITLE - Add the App Service Certificate to app DESCRIPTION - Failed to
>   add App Service certificate to the app, Check error for more details.
>   STATUS Error TIMESTAMP Tue Sep 13 2016 07:15:33 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer
>   Time) UTC TIMESTAMP Tue, 13 Sep 2016 06:15:33 GMT CORRELATION IDS 
>   clientNotification-57aec96e-534c-4a4c-84e9-42c990b60005 PERCENT
>   COMPLETED 100

Answer (score 0):

> I have also created a UK West App Service with the same domains validated

Azure App Service supports two different Certificate SKUs:

- S1 - Standard Certificate, which could protect both www and root domains
- W1 - Wild card Certificate, which could protect root domains with wild card

Based on your description, I assumed that you selected the Wild Card Certificate.

> TITLE - Add the App Service Certificate to app DESCRIPTION - Failed to add App Service certificate to the app, Check error for more details.

From the official [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site/) about How to buy and configure an SSL Certificate for your Azure App Service, we could find that when you purchase an App Service Certificate, you could select a subscription which could be used for web apps in the same subscription. Please try to check that whether your UK West App Service's description is the same as the description you provided to create your App Service Certificate.

Comment: It is an S1 certificate I have puchased as I only need to secure www and root.  I am planning on using traffic manager to load balance web apps across data centers.

I have successfully assigned the purchased certificate to my App Service in West Europe and ther certificate is in the list when I follow step 3 of the titorial you have refered to.

I am not sure where to find the description you are refering to?

Comment: Reading your comment again I assume you are asking if they are all in the same subscription and the answer is yes.

Comment: According to your comment, I purchased an S1 certificate to protect my domain named bruce-chen.cn on my side. Then I pointed bruce-chen.cn and www.bruce-chen.cn to the two Azure Web Apps. I could import the certificate and add SSL Bindings successfully. After I have completed the above steps, HTTPS certificate is available for both my two Azure Web Apps.

Comment: I have successfully purchased the S1 certificate and pointed the root and www domain at both web apps.  I have also successfully imported the certificate to the west europe web app.  When I import to UK West I get the error above which is not helping me much.  Is there anywhere else I can look for more detailed errors?